# Looping trough a std::map won't work

Tags: c++, sfml

**Answer** :

> Turns out the for loop did work.
>
> Lesson Learned :
>
> You might want to
>   try putting something in it to see if the code inside actually
>   executes....

---

As the title says I would like to loop trough a `std::map` filled with `sf::Sprite*`'s.

However when I try it like this :

```
(in .h file)    

std::map<std::string, sf::Texture*> textures;

(in .cpp file)

for (auto const &ent1 : textures)
{

}
```

It tells me that the `Debug Assertion Failed!`.

With this error "log" :

> Program: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
>   File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xtree
>   Line: 237
>
> Expression: map/set iterator not dereferencable

---

At this point I've tried reading some on how it works, and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I've been playing around with it, removing some parts and adding new ones.

I'be been removing `const`, removing the `&` and combining those two.

Comment: Are you modifying `textures` inside the loop?

Comment: @bornander I'm not doing anything inside it. Since I'm not sure how yet.

Comment: Can you compile & run the following code example in your cpp file? http://ideone.com/EOXzxr

Comment: @Miklas Yes, that works with the output : 1 - 1, 10 - 10, 5 - 5, 1 - 1, 10 - 10, 5 - 5

Comment: Try `const auto& ent1`. I think the modifier might be in the wrong place.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 `T const&` and `const T&` are completely equivalent.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Tried and it didn't work :/

Comment: It seems the for loop did actually work, the error we're created right after...

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you have corrupted the underlying storage of your `map` object and the VC++ debug runtime has protection code that tests if the data structure and iterators are in a valid state to avoid more damage. Clobbering memory and other undefined behaviour can result in all sorts of amusing results.

When in doubt about the semantics of something, consider making a test project in which you explore the concept, and if you run into a bug, try to isolate it as far as possible to rule out things.

Comment: My English ins't the best and my programming isn't either, lol. Do you have some links on what a container and a safeguard is? Never heard of those before. Should I add the way I "insert" objects into my map s well?